# java.lang.NullPointerException Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

Can anybody tells me where is here nullpointerexception? It says its on line 49,  "cigstxt = currentUser.get("inADay").toString();".
I don't see how line 49 could be nullpointer but line 50 couldn't.

> ```
> public class Welcome extends RegisterInformationActivity {
>
> Button logout;
> String cigstxt;
> String moneysavedtxt;
> String notsmokedtxt;
> String timesavedtxt;
>
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
>
>     TextView cigs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.days);
>     TextView moneysaved = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moneysaved);
>     TextView timesaved = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timesaved);
>     TextView notsmoked = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notsmoked);
>
>     final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
>
>     String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();
>
>     TextView txtuser = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
>
>     txtuser.setText(struser);
>
>      cigstxt = currentUser.get("inADay").toString();
>      moneysavedtxt = currentUser.get("days").toString();
>      notsmokedtxt = currentUser.get("inABox").toString();
>      timesavedtxt = currentUser.get("price").toString();
>
>     cigs.setText(String.valueOf(cigstxt));
>     moneysaved.setText(String.valueOf(moneysavedtxt));
>     timesaved.setText(String.valueOf(timesavedtxt));
>     notsmoked.setText(String.valueOf(notsmokedtxt));
>
>     logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);
>
>     logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             ParseUser.logOut();
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
> }}
> ```

logcat:

```
04-28 21:30:48.196  20869-20869/com.lacher.quitsmoking_doitnow E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lacher.quitsmoking_doitnow, PID: 20869
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lacher.quitsmoking_doitnow/com.lacher.quitsmoking_doitnow.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.lacher.quitsmoking_doitnow.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is with currentUser.get("inADay"). Place a debug point or an if condition and the check the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with a parse.com database, I messed it up (deleted last username). Code was good all along. Now it's working perfect!